# Jenkins - How to forcibly mark build successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Remote call on build4 failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:789)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:953)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:540)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.util.jna.GNUCLibrary
    at hudson.plugins.signal_killer.SignalKiller.sendSignal(SignalKiller.java:45)
    at hudson.plugins.signal_killer.SignalKiller.kill(SignalKiller.java:29)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.killByKiller(ProcessTree.java:216)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows$1.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:427)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows.killAll(ProcessTree.java:487)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:965)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:956)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to build4(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:252)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    ... 6 more
```

after my build. This error marked build as `FAILED`.

But I need to forcibly mark it as `SUCCESS`, because I got successful result of build -  *.exe link of my distrib.

I've tried to use [Jenkins Text Finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) plugin:

[Settings of JTF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yisOr.png)

It was looking for my regex in console output and mark build successful but it didn't work as I expected - it found regex, but didn't mark build successful.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible — the build result can only be marked as [worse](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/0bf1844/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java#L462-L466) than the existing result, and therefore the Text Finder plugin can only set your build as UNSTABLE or FAILED.

It would appear that you need to wait for a resolution to [JENKINS-20481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20481).  You should add as much detail to that ticket as you can to help.